# MYSQL Only display lowest value from resultset

Tags: mysql

I have the following statement:

```
select DATE(recieved_on) as Day, round (count(*) / 24)  AS 'average'
from message
where facility in ('FACID')
AND received on BETWEEN '2022-05-29 00:00:00' AND '2022-06-04 23:59:59'
GROUP BY DATE(received on);
```

Which provides the following result set:

| Day | average |
| --- | --- |
| date | value |
| date | value |
| date | value |
| date | value |
| date | value |
| date | value |
| date | value |

How can I display only the lowest value from the result set instead of all 7?

Comment: After group by add `ORDER BY average ASC` and after add `LIMIT 1`.  Also note that your query have an aggregate function. This may cause mismatch of `date` and `value`, so you can see the lowest `value` but it may not match with correct `date`.

Comment: @X999: There is only one date per average, so it will match!  (But when you have multiple days with same (lowest) average, then only any one of the dates will be show, and only the first date when you add the date to the order by.)

Comment: @Luuk It's not mentioned are `date`s unique or not. It's better to keep in mind it might cause mismatch.

Comment: After `GROUP BY DATE(received on)`, as mentioned in the query, the column `DATE(recieved_on) as Day` will hold unique values.

Answer (score 0):

You simply use order by and limit:

```
select DATE(recieved_on) as Day, round (count(*) / 24) AS 'average'
from message
where facility in ('FACID') AND received on BETWEEN '2022-05-29 00:00:00' AND '2022-06-04 23:59:59'
GROUP BY DATE(received on)
order by average
limit 1
```